# javascript to identify if bookmark toolbar is visible in mobile viewport in ios and andriod

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

Is there a way to identify whether bookmark/Navigation tool bar is visible using javascript.

I tried using window.innerHeight == $(window).height(), seems its not consistent as it is showing different in Landscape and Portrait.

Can any one suggest me a solution

Comment: By visible you mean in view port? Or just not hidden by css

Comment: Yes., in Viewport